# Squaring a number

Tags: c

This program is supposed to input a number and its square value, then tell me if right or wrong. I have some problems but I can't figure out what they are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float P;
    float q;
    float r;
    printf("Enter the value of p\n");
    scanf("%f",p);
    q= p*p;
    printf("Enter the square value of %f \n",p);
    scanf("%f",r);
    if (r = q){
        printf("You are right\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("you are wrong\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so tell me my mistakes

Comment: Your code is essentially unreadable, bu this 'scanf("%f",p);' cannot possibly modify 'p' since it is passsed by value.

Comment: Your first mistake was not learning how to run your program under a debugger.

Comment: @MartinJames I don't agree, it's the second error. First error is not using good compiler flags.

Comment: @jdarthenay there are good compiler flags?   ..  Oh never mind :)

Comment: @MartinJames At least some compiler settings such as no flags at all are worst than others, that's for sure.

Comment: @WeatherVane Definitely not, OP does not even reach that point...

Answer (score 2):

Please compile the program with flags `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` although the first mistake is always a compilation error (typo): replace `float P;` with `float p;` because C is case-sensitive.

Then you need to pass the *address* of a variable to `scanf`, these two lines

```
scanf("%f",r);
...
scanf("%f",p);
```

should be

```
scanf("%f",&r);
...
scanf("%f",&p);
```

Lastly, there is a syntax error where you test for equality with

```
if (r = q)
```

but this changes `r` and tests if it is non-0. With an integer type you should use

```
if (r == q)
```

but with floating point types, equality tests don't work well, please see why in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: @WeatherVane That's already said in my answer...

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I didn't have the feeling I was doing that, I'll try to turn my answer differently.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would upvote your edit if I could...

Comment: I upvoted your answer, it was good, I just improved the phrasing.